# setting the grids in the grid system next to each other

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Hey guys i am working on react with UNSPALSH API so on searcing a term i am retreiving list of details of the term in console and then in that upon running the map function i am retreiving the list of images in my screen so the thing is that i wanna make a column of 12 grids and want to assign 2 images next to each other in each row.
 so i wrote a code like

```
 <div className="row">
 <div className="col-lg-12">
 <div className="image-list col-lg-6">
 {images}
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

css file

```
.image-list img{
width: 90%;
height: 50vh;
margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

but it is giving me only one image in each row , here is the ss of the output https://ibb.co/343Rhb2

so how do i make it correct ?

Answer (score 0):

parent element of a `'col...` should be a `'row...`

in your case,

```
<div className="row">
  <div className="col-6">
    image goes here
  </div>
  <div className="col-6">
    image goes here
  </div>
</div>
```

if you need them inside a `col-12`, then

```
<div className="row">
  <div className="col-12">
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-6">
        image goes here
      </div>
      <div className="col-6">
        image goes here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```